# setting up stickiness for sharepoint site on F5 load balancer

Tags: sharepoint-2013, f5, ios-app-group

I have an iphone app based on sharepoint REST API CRUD operations. To do these operations, I get a fed auth cookie in the app launch using a custom login (sharepoint page) and thereafter all interactions are done using REST API calls. The problem we are facing is that randomly we are seeing abrupt session logout. While researching, we found out that this might be a stickiness based problem. So, we want to enable stickiness on our F5 load balancer. Now my question is- Is stickiness something that is browser dependant? If the requests keep moving via API calls and not through browser requests, which stickiness is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If your application supports cookies, then you can use cookie persistence. Otherwise, you can use source IP address affinity.